# C Which Bit Hack Is Better And Why?

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation

```
int n = 1; //Arbitrary value

for ( int i = 0;i < 8;i++ )
{
    printf( "%d",n & ( 1 << i ) ? 1 : 0 ); //Ternary
    printf( "%d",0 || n & ( 1 << i ) );    //Logical OR
}
```

Of the two expressions in the loop, which one would be the better choice to use for printing the 0 or 1 state of a binary value? (Basically printing the binary string representation).

Comment: Haha... they're both just as unreadable.

Comment: I don't understand the need for either the ternary expression or the logical or. The same output could be produced without either of these.

Comment: They are both hard to read, so from that point of view they are equally bad. And there is probably no noticable efficiency difference as well, because printing (probably) takes the most time, even buffered. The second *could* be faster, because there is no potential jump in it. But then again, the jump from the ternary operator would probably be optimized out anyway by the comiler.

Comment: So the consensus is: Unreadable. Ok ok, I surrender!

Answer (score 13):

The best would be

```
  (n >> i) & 0x1
```

It is more reliably branchless than any other method that goes through a "boolean" conversion.

When possible and reasonable, prefer shifting to the right, so that the bits that interest you end up in the correct positions to form the result you need, thus eliminating the need for any extra steps.

Comment: very nice, i have never thought about doing it this way.

Comment: Regarding efficiency: from the more ancient of my experience, *testing* n&(1<<i) was a bit better than testing (n>>i)&1  when 'i' is compile-time constant, and worse when i is variable. If the goal is to get 0 or 1 rather than a conditional test, that's likely inapplicable. However, these days most compilers will internally transform this common operation from one form into the other as best, so I no longer make this type of choice on efficiency. I like this answer best from readability, since it's not cluttered with conceptual 'boolean' intermediates which to my view just aren't helpful.

Answer (score 3):

How about `!!(n & (1 << i))` ?
Or `(n & (1 << i)) != 0`?

I thing both of those are better choices than the suggestons you make (and no, I didn't come up with the !! on my own, I read it in some code, and have picked it up from there - it's quite often used in Xen and Linux, for example)

To make it more readable, one could consider:

```
inline zero_or_one_bit(int n, int i)
{
    return !!(n & (1 << i));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of shifting left, shift right:

```
for (int i = 7; i >= 0; --i)
    printf("%d", (n >> i) & 1);
```

However, in a sense they might all be inefficient if `1 << i` was a microcoded instruction (which apparently is unlikely, according to the comments below).

Here is a version that only does constant shifts:

```
for (int i = 0, n2 = n; i < 8; i++, n2 <<= 1)
    printf("%d", (n2 >> 7) & 1);
```

Comment: Shift instructions are not microcoded on AMD processors, and I'm almost certain they are not on modern Intel processors either, but that's a littel harder to find out.

I like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like AndreyT's answer, but for completeness: you could easily get some more work out of that ternary (and you may be surprised how costly %d can be):

```
putc( (n & ( 1 << i ))!=0 ? '1' : '0', stdout );
```

And yes, if preferred

```
putc(   ((n>>i) & 1) + '0',  stdout );
```